# How to set a custom variable name through a function argument

Tags: c++, function

So what i am trying to do is basically get the second argument of a function, and making the second argument the name of a variable so i can easily store the users input. Here is my code

`

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void askAndStore(string question, string variable) 
{
    cout << question + " ";
    cin >> variable;
}
```

`

Comment: `string variable` -> `string &variable`.   Optionally - `string question` -> `const string &question`.    Even better, don't have `using namespace std` and use `std::string` directly.

Comment: What i am trying to do is make the string variable into like a custom name. for example ` askAndStore("What is your name?", usersName); `

Comment: In c++ once compiled the variable names no longer exist. You can't dynamically add new variables like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in C++.

You could have a `std::map<std::string, SomeType>` that you populate with your read-in names.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Values
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> values; 
public:
    void askAndStore(std::string question, std::string name) 
    {
        std::cout << question << " ";
        std::cin >> values[name];
    }

    std::string get(std::string name)
    {
        return values[name];
        // or return values.at(name); if name must already exist in values
    }
};

int main()
{
    Values user;
    user.askAndStore("What is your name?", "usersName");
}
```

That assumes your values are `std::string`s

Comment: You should avoid raw `std::map::operator[]` for get operations due to the side effect of typos adding empty values for erroneous keys. Instead check first with `std::map::find` (pre-C++ 20) or `std::map::contains` (for C++20).

Comment: @Casey `[]` might be fine for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

Pass variable by reference:

```
void askAndStore(string question, string& variable) 
{
    cout << question + " ";
    cin >> variable;
}
```

`string&` instead of `string`. Without using `&` you'd be passing in a copy of your varaible, using a reference type `string&` you pass the actual variable in which is then modified by `cin >> variable;`.

<sub>P.S Don't use `using namespace std;`</sub>